# How to Put Toggle Navigation in Left Side of the page

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

I have developed a custom page in wordpress .To make this page responsive , i have created a toggle navigation for navigation bar of page.But Toggle Navigation bar is coming right side of the page , i want it to be appear in left side of the page.

My second Query :-

I want to know that how we can decide that at which width of browser, the toggle navigation bar should come.

Please help me to achieve above both targets

```css
body
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
}
.navMenu
{
 width:100%;
 background-color:#440000;
}

ul.Menu
{
    list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:18px;
 width:100%;
 position:relative; 
 display:inline-block;
 margin-top:0px;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:center;
 padding-left:28%;
 
}


li.Menu
{
    display: inline-block;

 
}

.list{
    float:left;
 margin-left:2%;
}

.Listclass
{
 color:#942218;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.searchform
{
 margin-top: -4px;
}

.navbar .brand {
max-height: 50px;
overflow: visible;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
background-color:white;
}
.navbar a.navbar-brand {padding: 0px 8px 0px;}

.navbar-default {
    background-color:white;
    border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: blue;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
     background-color: white;
    background-image: none;
    /*border: 1px solid black; */
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar
{
 background-color: black;
}
.Listclass
{
 color:#942218;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.MenuDIV
{
 width:70%;
}

.form1
{
 float:right;
 margin-top: -75px;
    margin-right: 326px;
}
.navMenu
{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navMenu">
<nav class="navbar" role="banner">

<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left MenuDIV" style="width:70%">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right Menu">
  <li class="list"><a class="active" href="#HOME"><img src="http://10.37.4.179/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/home-active.png"></a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Community">COMMUNITY</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Board">BOARD</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#RESOURES">RESOURES</a></li>
  <li class="list"><a class="Listclass" href="#Contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</nav>
<form class="navbar-form form1" role="search">
    <div class="input-group add-on">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Can we have a look at your code?

Comment: We need to know what you did for your first query, what your page looks like and what your page should look like. Code would help a lot

Comment: i have added my code . Kindly look into this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.in genaral for toggle "float:right" css property will be there you can change it to float:left then menu will come left side,
2.to find width of toggle menu firefox browser press ctrl+shift+m  then resize untill get toggle menu

Comment: Hello sir , i have added my code . kindly look into this and suggest me what changes i have to do

Comment: its correct sir but i want to put search box inline of this navigation bar like what i have done in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code help you  :

```
 $(function () {
    $("#openmenu").click(function() {
      $('#menuleftcontent').animate({
       width: "toggle"
      });
    });
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dGA8/316/)